# Clarification on an MSDN sockets article

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asyncsocket

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300760.aspx#S7) article covers some basics of simple sync and async servers.  I have my own synchronous server I'm looking to convert to asynchronous and found this article.

In Figure 7 there is a basic async server.  Why does the server's `Start` method loop over `_serverSocket.BeginAccept(...)` 10 times?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think the "server" should handle up to 10 connections at once - that's all. After accepting one they begin receiving and startup another possible connection - so the server could have more than 10 connections at once if receiving is very slow/long lasting) - but I guess you get the idea...

This is where the "...significantly higher performance..." is :)